# sufficient points to answer questions but can't

Tags: support, reputation

I would like to answer [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9563/how-can-i-monitor-a-website-for-malicious-changes-to-the-files) question, however it states that I will need 10 reputation to answer it as it has been protected by the Community. I currently have 101 reputation, why should I be seeing this message?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the error? That will help the SE devs figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That question has been protected because it received four spam or very low quality answers.   We protect question that attract spam to prevent spammers from continuing to target them with new accounts.

You are unable to answer the question because you need to get 10 reputation to answer a protected question *other than the 100 reputation points for associating your account with your other StackExchange accounts*.  See [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

> Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question. However, **the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check**, so you must have earned 10 or more reputation *on that specific site* to answer a protected question.

Since you are interested in answering the question but don't have the reputation to do so, I went ahead and removed the protection. (**EDIT**: Now that you have answered I re-protected the question.)

Comment: Perfectly lovely response.